# AWS Cloudformation run command once per stack update and creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a working AWS CloudFormation template that deploys a web application stack. All the required commands are currenlty added as `UserData` for each EC2 instance.

After the creation / update of the stack I'd like to run a cache clear. This clear should only run once within the stack and not for every webserver which is being updated.

I already had a look at `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` but this seems to also target each resource / instance which is deployed.

Comment: Where do you want the command to be run? On a specific instance or externally, such as a AWS Lambda function? Even if you want to run it inside a EC2 instance, what you can do is have an AWS Lambda function that calls SSM Run Command against a specific instance, and this clears the cache. Sounds like this is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass pseudo-parameter value [`AWS::NotificationARNs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-notificationarns) to your `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` - these are ARNs of SNS topics (apart from default one it's possible that you defined additional), to which the stack sends snotifications. You can then react on various stack events.